# How to apply OR to JOIN...ON statement

Tags: mysql

I have table `place` contains `author_id` and table `place_user_relation` contains columns `user_id`,`place_id`

I want to fetch `place.id` where `place_user_relation.user_id=1` or `place.author_id=1`.Problem is this criteria is in two tables. To my knowledge, I wrote a wrong query:

```
    SELECT r.*,p.* FROM place_user_relation as r
    JOIN place as p
    ON p.place_id=r.place OR p.author_id=1
    WHERE r.user_id=1
    /*I also tried WHERE r.user_id=1 OR p.author_id=1*/
```

in which contains an OR in ON statement, seems I can't do that. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight this join query returns empty set.When select * from relation_place_user where user_id=1 is empty but when select * from place where author_id=1 return 3 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.id
  FROM place_user_relation r JOIN place p ON p.id = r.place_id
 WHERE p.author_id = 1
    OR r.user_id = 1
```

Comment: Well, it's the right answer and I wrote in my question that I have tried this, it was an error because of an typo... Thanks for your effort anyway.

Comment: This query is incomplete, seems we should use right join instead of join and add 'group by r.place_id'. Since if using join, the result will not contain place that has no relation with users(has no record in place_user_relation) and repetitive rows of one place that has several records in place_user_relation table. I don't know why, but I just tried this out....

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.*,p.* FROM place_user_relation as r
JOIN place as p
ON p.place_id=r.place
WHERE r.user_id=1
union 
SELECT r.*,p.* FROM place_user_relation as r, place as p
    WHERE r.user_id=1 AND p.author_id=1
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is probably just not liking the fact that one of the conditions in the ON clause is only referencing one of the tables. Try making it a CROSS JOIN and moving all of the conditions into the WHERE clause, and using TRUE as the ON clause (since ON is apparently required)...

```
SELECT r.*,p.* FROM place_user_relation as r
CROSS JOIN place as p
ON true
WHERE (p.place_id=r.place OR p.author_id=1) and r.user_id=1
```

The UNION solution suggested by @arnon-rotem-gal-oz should also work.